# Whats wrong with this $return?

Tags: php, html, return

I need to fix the following, could please help me?

```
$return .= "<a href='<?php echo $kinsource ;?>' class="lightbox" rel="pics"><img src='<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url')."/timthumb.php?src=".$kinsource."&w=120&h=120&zc=1";?>' alt=""/></a>";
```

Comment: Well, what **is** wrong?

Comment: Define "fix."  What's wrong with it?  In what way does this code not do what you expect it to do?  What does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got `<?php ?>` inside existing PHP code. You cannot nest `<?php ?>`. Since you are using double quotes, simple variables like `$kinsource` will be interpolated but the function call to `get_bloginfo()` will have to be concatenated in. Switch all other double quotes inside the string to single quotes.

```
$return .= "<a href='$kinsource' class='lightbox' rel='pics'><img src='" . get_bloginfo('template_url') ."/timthumb.php?src='{$kinsource}&w=120&h=120&zc=1' alt=''/></a>";
```

Note, I've also surrounded `$kinsource` in `{}` when it runs into other strings for readability, though it won't negatively affect the parsing in this situation if that isn't done.

Comment: Thank you, it is better.. however not yet working properly. The img src url is broken. I only get this: themes/source/timthumb.php?src=

Comment: Done! I just had to remove a single quote from your answer. Thank so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the inner quotation marks.

```
$return .= "<a href='<?php echo $kinsource ;?>' class=\"lightbox\" rel=\"pics\"><img src='<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url').\"/timthumb.php?src=\".$kinsource.\"&w=120&h=120&zc=1\";?>' alt=\"\"/></a>";
```

Either that or you have `<?php ?>` tags inside of your php, which doesn't work if you are already within a php block.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, you need to fix those unescaped double quotes in double quotes.

```
$return .= '<a href="'.$kinsource.'" class="lightbox" rel="pics"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'"/timthumb.php?src="'.$kinsource.'"&w=120&h=120&zc=1" alt=""/></a>";
```

You don't need to echo in a `<?php ?>` when you can just concatenate.